# Python, how to import a .py file

Tags: python, file, import, module

I have a directory with two `.py` files in my `C:\Python27\word_data` called `main.py` and `gethtml.py`.

I want to import `gethtml.py` in my `main.py`, print `def` from that file, and I tried to do like this:

```
import gethtml

print gethtml.getHtmlText()
```

When I run this in a Python shell I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    execfile("word_rank/main.py")
 File "word_rank/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import gethtml
ImportError: No module named gethtml
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If you run this from the `word_rank` directory, it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check that the working directory for your python session is the directory containing your two python files.  You can get Python to report the location of the current working directory as follows:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

Python will look in the current working directory (and in some directories in PATH) for the file you are trying to import.  Not being able to find the file would give the error above.

Comment: I've added you suggestion, but I'm not quite sure how to use it... It gives  me the same error. should I add something in brackets of `getcwd` or? my file looks like this now:

`import os`
`os.getcwd()`

`import gethtml`

`print gethtml.getHtmlText()`

Comment: yea I've managed to get it work with your suggestion and adding `from word_rank` before `import gethtml`,

thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it's working.  Note that adding `import os` and `os.getcwd()` does not change the working directory, only prints it out for you.